# Is it safe to leave the Remote Desktop Services port on the default?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server

I operate some Windows Servers (with Windows Server 2019 Standard) that work with sensitive business informations. These servers are accessed by Remote Desktop Services (mstsc.exe), using the default port which is 3389.

I recently read on Quora that there are a large amount of mstsc logins on sale on the dark web.

So I wonder that is it safe to leave the Remote Desktop Services port on the default (which is 3389)?

Comment: I've been hacked twice while I was sure my security was set properly because I used port 3389. I would definitely say its not safe! Not in 2020.

Comment: If you have concerns on port security, you are allowed to change the lisenting port for Remote Desktop.
Reference link:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/change-listening-port

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is safe to leave this port open as that is how we access our Business Servers.

Firewall should be ON of course, and you must have Business VPN installed for access to the machine.

That is, all standard Business Security must be in place and properly maintained.

Comment: I've been hacked twice while I was sure my security was set properly because I used port 3389. I would definitely say its not safe! Not in 2020.

Comment: That would not happen if you have strong Business VPN in place to protect. Our business protected thusly have not been hacked .

Comment: If you are behind VPN, but the VPN is configured improperly, then its still a risk. For me it is easier to have a NAT rule with a different port than 3389, keeping the server with 3389 is fine in that case, and using something like RDP Guard to protect against password guessing. That way you don't need a VPN. I'm more concerned with this answer the way it is formulated. Someone quickly readong the answer will read the first line, think: okay, its fine, not realizing the big IF. That's basically my problem here.